# Add user to table and use users id while adding data to second table while user registration

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

In my controller final part of user registration is:

```
_context.Users.Add(user);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

Now I want to get `ID` of that entry and use it while I'm adding other data to second table, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `User` primary key is `auto-generated` then you can do as follows:

```
......

_context.Users.Add(user);

SecondTable secondTable = new SecondTable();
secondTable.UserId = user.Id; // <-- Just point the user Id here
_context.SecondTables.Add(secondTable);

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: <-- Here you can set it > I cannot set it because that Id is generated by SQL server while adding entity to table. How can I get it ?

Comment: You just need to point it what I have done! EF will do the rest during the `SaveChanges()` is successful.

Comment: I've tried this method And when I registered user it received Id  1, (first entry)
But Entry in SecondTable had UserId "-2147482647" , how could this happen ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have auto-incremented ID coulmn, then it will be easy to get that ID (after invoking `SaveChanges()`):

```
var id = _context.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.Id).First().Id
```

or if you manually assing ID, then it's even simplier:

```
var id = user.Id;
```

Comment: If you have auto-incremented ID coulmn, you event don't need this round trip to the database. Just need to point it as I have done during insert. EF will do the rest during the `SaveChanges()` is successful.

Answer (score 0):

after saving changes, entity gets its id from database. 
also you can use navigation properties and complete all of changes in one transaction( save changes)